# "OSError: [Errno 127] Key has expired" - Pandas df.to_csv method

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, oserror

When running the following `df.to_csv()` line as part of a `multiprocessing` process:

```py
filtered_chunk.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, "filtered_{}".format(csv_filename)), mode='a+')
```

I get the following error. I can't figure out what the issue is (the snippet below is for one `multiprocessing` process):

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 109, in worker
  <insert stacktrace for code I wrote...>
    filtered_chunk.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, "filtered_{}".format(csv_filename)), mode='a+')
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3170, in to_csv
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 185, in save
  File "/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 418, in get_handle
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1342, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1314, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1443, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1483, in _fill_cache
OSError: [Errno 127] Key has expired: '/home/User1/miniconda3/envs/part_ii_dev-conda/lib/python3.8'
```

After every process fails with the stacktrace above, I get a `Bus error (core dumped)` printout.

"Key has expired" makes me think of something that requires verification or provides time-limited access (file pointers? keys/tickets to access a server?). I ran the script in a `tmux` session on a server, so I don't think access to the server would've been an issue (some googling of error 127 pointed me to mounting issues but I don't think that's an issue here). Since the script failed at the `get_handle` method with basically returns a file handle, file pointers seems to be the problem but I'm not sure why.

If it helps, I'm using `multiprocessing` to parallelise a function, but different processes write to different csv files, so that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Is your home directory also mounted on a Windows machine on which you changed password? The "Key has expired" can happen when mounting a shared directory from a Windows machine with changed or expired password.

Comment: As far as I know it was an Ubuntu machine, rather than WSL. I simply reran the code and it worked.

Comment: My university uses the Kerberos protocol which requires authentication tickets to be periodically updated. If a Python script using resources on another local server is ran in `tmux` for too long, I sometimes end up with this error. The university developed a special "`tmux`+Kerberos" program we have to use to prevent being disconnected.

Comment: That's interesting, do you have a link to that? I was accessing the server (which I ran `tmux` on) using Kerberos authentication too. I thought that the point of `tmux` was so programs don't stop when you get disconnected.

Comment: Sorry @peractio, I don't have access to the source of the program so I can't explain how it works. I'm also not familiar with Kerberos. What I think I understand though is that client connections (like tmux) to a server using Kerberos must take steps to periodically re-validate their Kerberos ticket. So this custom program probably periodically calls `kinit -R`. Maybe this could help: https://iain.cx/src/ktmux/